# What is Semantic Wiki?

Tags: php, semantics, wiki, semantic-web, semantic-mediawiki

I am a PHP Developer and completely new about the terms like Semantic Web, Semantic Wiki, Semantic MediaWiki etc.

Got the work requirement about Semantic Wiki couple of days before and then I explored lot about it but didn't get exact idea about it.

Still confused..!!! and I've some doubt which I would like to clear from you.

1. What exactly Semantic Wiki is?
2. What is the purpose of it?
3. Why and when we use it?
4. Is it a PHP Framework or something like that?

I'll be better if you give me answer in simple, real life comparing examples instead whatever explained on WikiPedia or other its blogs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe how you think you understand it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_wiki) mentioned in the comments is quite theoretic. It starts with terms such as *knowledge* that need a few explanations.

I take a deep breath and try to explain a few things...

**1. What exactly is a Semantic Wiki?**

To make things simple, you probably know what is a Wiki. The point is probably about semantics, you have [an exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/725261/1207019) about this, but I try here to summarize. According to the [Wikipedia article on *Semantics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics), this is about relationships between words.

The current Web is largely syntactic: a human (or system) needs to know the syntax of a language (including grammar) of a page in order to capture the meaning of the words. This is why I can't personally understand a page in Chinese or Arabian but will guess things in Dutch or Danish: these languages are European, will have a grammar similar and an etymology close to the languages I know.

In 2001, Tim Berners-Lee (father of the Web) et al. introduced in [a seminal article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-semantic-web/) the idea that the Web would become very interesting if page terms where exposed on the semantic side as a complement to syntax informations. This is the concept of [the semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web). Such an organization of data would have several advantages including [predicate calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) (also called [first-order-logic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderLogic.html) -> that article is succinct) and internationalization. An important element in predicate calculus is about data quality.

The semantic topic is really huge: if you are really interested then you should read a book about it.

A semantic Wiki is simply a Wiki that takes advantage of semantics rather than syntax. It has the advantage of a Wiki: the collaborative aspect can be precious for data quality. Note: you have several standards for semantic informations (RDF/OWL, Microdata/RDFA/JSON-LD).

**2. What is the purpose of it?**

At first glance, the main interest of the semantic Web is for search engines: Web pages would be easier to crawl with semantic informations. Web crawler are in fact the main applications processing Web pages.

With some tooling (e.g. an RDF parser), a semantically-structured  Wiki could also be easier to process by third-party software than a purely syntactic Wiki. The client could easily build its own knowledge base.

If you want to understand the deep interest of such a system, think about [IBM Watson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFR3lOm_xhE). But **for such a result, a huge infrastructure is needed**.

Using a semantic Wiki has the advantages of a Wiki. Think about data quality: for Watson, IBM analyzed the content of Wikipedia - they talk about the [UIMA architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIMA) for that analyze. In the fourth part are a few words about DBPedia which is a project analyzing the semantics of Wikipedia articles.

But few non-semantic wikis have the quality of Wikipedia.

**3. Why and when we use it?**

*Why* ? You have several reasons for using a semantic system. The most obvious use of a semantic system is internationalization. Take a look at the Unesco site [in English](http://en.unesco.org/), [in Chinese](http://www.unesco.org/new/zh), [in Arabian](http://www.unesco.org/new/ar): three different sites with a pure syntactic solution. There are also many other advantages related to deduction (the predicate calculus topic). An example of a *simple* deduction application for search engines is [Google Knowledge Graph](https://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html) (*simple* is here a blur point about structured data impacting the functionalities, not the project itself: in a few years it could become something really impressive). Most works on the topic are academic. There is a need for a huge infrastructure to have an effective system. And first of all, you need to understand very well the question of the semantic Web.

For the *when* part, I would say when your project is backed by a large organization and when you are really familiar with the topic. Another case  for using semantic informations would be to help Web crawling. But as far as I know, if Google loads currently Microdata/RDFA/JSON-LD, this has a very light impact on Web ranking.

**4. Is it a PHP Framework or something like that?**

It would be difficult for me to advise you about a PHP solution.

The [Ace Wiki](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/acewiki/) is a good example. The linked page gives access to a geography Wiki which is a sample and the *GitHub* account of the project. Unfortunately for you, it is in Java.

[Semantic MediaWiki](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/) is an extension of MediaWiki to enrich pages with semantic informations. It provides a SPARQL interface (the SQL for knowledge bases) and an RDF export. These two functions suggest that the primary data storage is graph-based (I have no experience of this).

Don't be mistaken: you will cross [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) but this is NOT a semantic wiki. This is a semantic form of Wikipedia. However, this is quite an important knowledge base.